# Phone Numbers to be ignored

Tags: iphone, call

Apparently someone has given my number has his telephone number to a whole bunch of offices, and I am getting a lot of calls on my phone asking for him!

Is there a setting on the iPhone 3GS - OS 4.0.2 to set a phone number to not ring, and not vibrate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without jailbreaking, your only option is the network operator's (AT&T, Verizon, etc) blacklist option. There may be a monthly fee, $5/mo on AT&T for example, but will allow you block receiving calls from any number you like. iBlacklist will work if your phone is jailbroken, but it costs $11.99 - a little high in my opinion.

Comment: Just to note that you've assumed their network is AT&T. Other operators offer similar services, possibly for free depending on where you live.

Comment: When I wrote that, the only network *was* AT&T. Verizon and Sprint hadn't received the iPhone yet. I'm not sure what the other networks' options are, but I'm sure they have something similar. Anyone on Verizon or Sprint, feel free to chime in.

Comment: Maybe you should say that one could call their operator for blacklisting options and list AT&T as an example instead of saying your only option is AT&T blacklist. While in the US the iPhone was only available on AT&T the iPhone was already being sold outside the US and this is a global site.

Answer (score 9):

You can always make a silent ring tone as your default ring tone.  Be sure to assign ring tones to your contacts that you want to hear from.

Comment: Actually, on reading a bit more about the Blacklist app I posted above, I think that's all it does too.

Comment: Also: apparently incoming calls that say "Blocked" (caller ID/name blocked) can't be assigned a silent ringtone.

Answer (score 5):

I was wrong! My other answer was incorrect and has been deleted. There's an app in the App Store called "Blacklist" that looks to do exactly what you want. I missed it before because I'm not in the US and it isn't available in my country, but your profile says you're in Philly, so you should be golden. $1.99.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blacklist/id310726855?mt=8

Comment: This only works when the ringer is ON. This still makes the phone vibrate regardless of if the number is in the black list.

Comment: As of iOS 5 the above comment is not necessarily true. You can use the Accessibility features to [design a custom vibration pattern](http://www.pcworld.com/article/242238/how_to_use_custom_vibrations_in_ios_5.html), and make one that doesn't vibrate.

Answer (score 3):

I was anticipating a problem like this a while back so I turned to Google voice to help. This won't help you now, or even after the fact, but for future reference, you get spam control from the dashboard and some other neat features. I found that I give my Google voice number out more freely because I trust the tools that allow me to block as needed.

Here's a useful link that talks about blocking with [Google Voice](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115089). Scroll down to the "Spam from Individual Callers" section.

Answer (score 2):

Create a silent ringtone with GarageBand. (This assumes you're on a Mac. I'm not sure how to get ringtones into iTunes on a Windows machine.)

Send it to iTunes so you you can sync it over to your iPhone.

Create a new contact called "IGNORE" or something that will let you know it's one of those unwanted callers. Assign the silent ringtone to that contact. (this allows you to keep your default ringtone audible)

As other numbers call that you don't want to be bothered by, you can just add them to that existing contact.

You hear the ringtones from people you want, and you don't from the annoying callers.

Problem solved. :)

Comment: I usually leave my phone on vibrate during the day.  Hence the question about setting to neither ring nor vibrate.