# Software to Hide SMS and Call

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phone Numbers to be ignored](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/522/phone-numbers-to-be-ignored)

I'm looking for software that can hide incoming sms and call for certain number for iPhone.
Is there any suggestion?
No Jailbreak please.

Comment: Also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10853/how-do-i-block-smss-on-an-iphone

Comment: Long story short, there's no (unjailbroken) apps, only hacks.